# I need help to build following programming logic

Tags: algorithm

I have an array-

```
$hubnode[1]=array(1,2,3,5,10,11,12,13,15,16,17);
$hubnode[2]=array(1,2,3,5,10,11,12,13,15,16,17);
$hubnode[3]=array(2,10,11,15);
$hubnode[4]=array(1,2,3,5,10,11,12,13,15,16,17);
$hubnode[5]=array(1,2,3,5,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17);
$hubnode[6]=array(2,10,11,13,15);
$hubnode[7]=array(1,2,3,5,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17);
$hubnode[8]=array(1,2,3,5,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17);
```

I need to make every unique possible group of 8 members by taking 1 digit from each line.
in a group all 8 digit will be unique.

no group can't be repeat during count.for example valid groups are:-

$group[1]=1,2,10,3,4,11,5,8;

$group[2]=1,3,10,2,4,11,9,8;

........................etc

Comment: The question is under-defined: what do you mean by "groups cannot be repeated"? Do you mean that all elements must be distinct? Does order matter? Is `{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1}` a valid group? If the answer is "yes", is it different from `{1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This site is for specific questions, not for “do it for me, please” kind of stuff.

Comment: yes all elements in group must be distinct.your indicating groups are not valid.I have to count total number of groups also whiches will fulfill this condition.thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: he said that in a group all 8 digits have to be unique so 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1 isn't an option. Also he said that he want's all unique possibilities where you map 1 number to 1 group so I guess we can assume (although this was a good question) that 2,1,3 isn't the same as 1,2,3 but that indeed needs clarification

Comment: You can make eight nested loops, each picking an element of the corresponding array. The innermost loop should make a copy of the eight-element array, sort it, and check against all eight-number groups that you've seen so far. If this is a new group, store it in the set of unique groups.

Comment: I think it required a depth first search but could not figured out fully.somebody please help

Comment: DFS doesn't really seem too good for this, but maybe I'm not looking close enough ;) My answer is basically a very lengthy version of @dasblinkenlight algorithm. As I said you won't really run from the complexity unless you can come up with some very clever way of discarding groups that for certain cannot exist beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try some dynamic programming!

1) What if you'd have only 1 group? Then it would be easy, right? Simply N possibilities where N is the size of the group. For instance:

```
$hubnode[1]=array(1,2,3);
group[1] = 1
group[2] = 2
group[3] = 3
```

2) Now what if we add another group? Let's say:

$hubnode[2]=array(3,4);

You get:

```
group[1] = 1,3
group[2] = 1,4
group[3] = 2,3
group[4] = 2,4
group[5] = 3,4
```

What does this show us? Well basically when computing groups for N hubs we can take the groups for N-1 hubs and to each of them add the element from hub N if it is not in that group.

What I mean is:

- for N = 1 you had a group "group[1] = 1", now you take from hub2 all the elements one by one and try to apply them to this group creating a new one each time. In this case this creates groups {1,3} and {1,4}. In case of group[3] it only creates group {3,4} because {3,3} does not satisfy our condition about unique elements.

3) what if we cannot at point N apply any number from a hub to a group? well we discard that group. For instance when you have {1,3} and then {1} you first get 2 groups 1 and 3 but you cannot do anything with the first one so discard it.

Now the question is how to efficiently check whether X is in group[Y]. This is a good question since we cannot keep the groups sorted (as the order matters) unless we also add a label to each value from which group it came from. Then using binary search we can check if the given number is in the group.

4) as a kind of performance boost (should you need it) you can process the arrays from the smallest to the largest as the smallest one will give you the biggest constraint on possible solutions.

Worst case scenario we can simply linearly check each group...

The complexity will be huge but in the worst case scenario you will simply have a lot of possibilities so don't think you can do that much about it... Worst case scenario you will have 8 groups with **n** distinct numbers which means n^8, woah!

p.s. as Ondrej said in the comment section you should try to come up with something on your own - I replied only because I'm practicing for an interview ;)